# why isn't the command exit log being shown when I pipe it through a bash function?

Tags: bash, unix, pipe

I want to create a script that runs multiple commands in parallel. I want it to exit all those commands when I git CTRL+C

The problem I am having is when I pipe the output of the first ping command to a bash function it does not print the exit logs. i.e. the logs containing `"rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.808/6.855/6.906/0.040 ms"`

How can I get this working? thanks :)

```
#!/bin/bash
trap terminate SIGINT
terminate(){
    echo "terminating started"
    pkill -SIGINT -P $$
    echo "terminating finished"
    exit
}

log () {
        sed -e "s/^/[$1]: /"
}

#the rest of your code goes here
ping 1.1.1.1 |& log "first_log" &
ping bbc.com  |& sed -e "s/^/[bbc_log]: /"&
wait
```

Here are the logs:

```
dewi@pop-os:~/tmp/bashtest$ bash bashtest
[first_log]: PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
[first_log]: 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=9.37 ms
[first_log]: 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=9.31 ms
[bbc_log]: PING bbc.com(2a04:4e42::81 (2a04:4e42::81)) 56 data bytes
[bbc_log]: 64 bytes from 2a04:4e42::81 (2a04:4e42::81): icmp_seq=1 ttl=250 time=7.82 ms
[first_log]: 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=9.42 ms
[bbc_log]: 64 bytes from 2a04:4e42::81 (2a04:4e42::81): icmp_seq=2 ttl=250 time=6.32 ms
[first_log]: 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=9.32 ms
^C[bbc_log]: 64 bytes from 2a04:4e42::81: icmp_seq=3 ttl=250 time=6.66 ms
[bbc_log]:
[bbc_log]: --- bbc.com ping statistics ---
[bbc_log]: 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
[bbc_log]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.317/6.930/7.816/0.641 ms
terminating started
terminating finished
dewi@pop-os:~/tmp/bashtest$
```

Mant thanks :)

---

Edit: here is a simpler version of the problem:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

log() {
    sed 's/^/[log]: /'
}

if [[ $1 == 1 ]]; then
    ping 1.1.1.1 2>&1 | sed 's/^/[log]: /' &
else
    ping 1.1.1.1 2>&1 | log &
fi

wait
```

```
$ ./tst.sh 1
[log]:
[log]: Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
[log]: Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=55
[log]:
[log]: Ping statistics for 1.1.1.1:
[log]:     Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
[log]: Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
[log]:     Minimum = 20ms, Maximum = 20ms, Average = 20ms
[log]: Control-C
```

```
$ ./tst.sh 2
[log]:
[log]: Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
[log]: Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=59ms TTL=55

$
```

Both runs above were interrupted at about the same time. Why does the first version, calling sed directly, print the final stats from the ping while the 2nd version, calling sed through a function, doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a SIGINT to `sed` at the same time that you are sending it to `ping`.  The `sed` is terminating before it sees `ping`'s final message.

A simple workaround would be to use a version of `sed` that can ignore SIGINT.  eg:

```
perl -p -e 'BEGIN{$SIG{INT}="IGNORE";} s/^/['"$1]: /"
```

As to the excellent questions raised by @EdMorton, I would just say that signal handling in the shell (and in Unix generally) is fickle.  The behavior will greatly depend on the ordering of events.

Comment: This makes sense but I see the same behavior even if I comment out the `pkill` line so the parent shell is being interrupted but it's not sending interrupts to the background children it had spawned so those child processes should just happily live out their lives as children of the init process from that point shouldn't they? So what THEN is causing the final info from the ping command to not appear...

Comment: I updated the question to more concisely show the problem behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in addition to [@WilliamPursell's point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73090854/1745001) that you could be interrupting your sed process at the same time as you're interrupting your ping process, you also need to group your commands when putting them in the background:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

log() {
    sed 's/^/[log]: /'
}

if [[ $1 == 1 ]]; then
    { ping 1.1.1.1 2>&1 | sed 's/^/[log]: /'; } &
else
    { ping 1.1.1.1 2>&1 | log; } &
fi

wait
```

```
$ ./tst.sh 1
[log]:
[log]: Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
[log]: Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=55
[log]:
[log]: Ping statistics for 1.1.1.1:
[log]:     Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
[log]: Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
[log]:     Minimum = 21ms, Maximum = 21ms, Average = 21ms
[log]: Control-C
```

```
$ ./tst.sh 2
[log]:
[log]: Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
[log]: Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=55
[log]:
[log]: Ping statistics for 1.1.1.1:
[log]:     Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
[log]: Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
[log]:     Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 29ms, Average = 29ms
[log]: Control-C
```

Why that's necessary and why that difference shows up when piping to a function but not when piping directly to sed - I could guess but I'd rather someone who **knows** fills us in on that.

Comment: hmmm not working on my machine. what version of bash are you running? mine is: GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)`. Please clarify "not working" (and never just say "not working" when describing any problem in software or in life as it's hard to fix anything given just "not working"!) - no change in behavior, different undesirable behavior, something else?

Comment: ah sorry. I mean it is acting the same weird behaviour the way I described.
i.e. no "Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:" etc
Many thanks for your efforts Ed

Comment: You're welcome. Did you resolve the issue that @WilliamPursell mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/73090854/1745001 too? You probably need to fix both issues for a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Force GNU Parallel to ignore SIGINT, so it will receive the input from the dying `ping`s:

```
$ parallel -o --lb --tag ping {='$SIG{INT}=sub {}'=} ::: 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9

1.1.1.1 PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
1.1.1.1 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=11.6 ms
8.8.8.8 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
8.8.8.8 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=19.0 ms
9.9.9.9 PING 9.9.9.9 (9.9.9.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
9.9.9.9 64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=18.2 ms
9.9.9.9 64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=38.4 ms
1.1.1.1 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=38.1 ms
8.8.8.8 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=43.3 ms
9.9.9.9 64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=18.5 ms
1.1.1.1 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=12.2 ms
8.8.8.8 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=19.2 ms
9.9.9.9 64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=36.6 ms
1.1.1.1 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=3.19 ms
8.8.8.8 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=19.1 ms
^C
9.9.9.9
9.9.9.9 --- 9.9.9.9 ping statistics ---
9.9.9.9 5 packets transmitted, 4 received, 20% packet loss, time 4005ms
9.9.9.9 rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.166/27.903/38.404/9.611 ms
1.1.1.1 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=10.1 ms
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 --- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1.1.1.1 5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4004ms
1.1.1.1 rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.189/15.042/38.147/11.991 ms
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
8.8.8.8 5 packets transmitted, 4 received, 20% packet loss, time 4003ms
8.8.8.8 rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.992/25.157/43.299/10.474 ms
```

Or:

```
$ parallel -o --lb --tagstring '[{}_log]:' ping {='$SIG{INT}=sub {}'=} ::: 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9
```

`-o` was introduced in version 20220522.